# Apache Spark - Finding Array/List/Set subsets

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes each one having Array[String] as one of the columns. For each entry in one dataframe, I need to find out subsets, if any, in the other dataframe. An example is here:

DF1:

```
----------------------------------------------------
           id : Long    |   labels : Array[String]
---------------------------------------------------
         10             |    [label1, label2, label3]
         11             |    [label4, label5]
         12             |    [label6, label7]
```

DF2:

```
----------------------------------------------------
         item : String |   labels : Array[String]
---------------------------------------------------
         item1         |   [label1, label2, label3, label4, label5]
         item2         |   [label4, label5]
         item3         |   [label4, label5, label6, label7]
```

After the subset operation I described, the expected o/p should be

DF3:

```
----------------------------------------------------
         item : String |   id : Long
---------------------------------------------------
         item1         |   [10, 11]
         item2         |   [11]
         item3         |   [11, 12]
```

It is guaranteed that the DF2, will always have corresponding subsets in DF1, so there won't be any left over elements.

Can someone please help with the right approach here ? It looks like for each element in DF2, I need to scan DF1 and do subset operation (or set subtraction) on the 2nd column until I find all the subsets and exhaust the labels in that row and while doing that accumulate the list of "id" fields. How do I do this in compact and efficient manner ? Any help is greatly appreciated. Realistically, I may have 100s of elements in DF1 and 1000s of elements in DF2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to perform this kind of operation in an efficient way. However, here is one possible solution using `UDF` as well as Cartesian join.

The `UDF` takes two sequences and checks if all strings in the first exists in the second:

```
val matchLabel = udf((array1: Seq[String], array2: Seq[String]) => {
  array1.forall{x => array2.contains(x)}
})
```

To use Cartesian join, it needs to be enabled as it is computationally expensive.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", true)
```

The two dataframes are joined together utilizing the `UDF`. Afterwards the resulting dataframe is grouped by the `item` column to collect a list of all ids. Using the same `DF1` and `DF2` as in the question:

```
val DF3 = DF2.join(DF1, matchLabel(DF1("labels"), DF2("labels")))
  .groupBy("item")
  .agg(collect_list("id").as("id"))
```

The result is as follows:

```
+-----+--------+
| item|      id|
+-----+--------+
|item3|[11, 12]|
|item2|    [11]|
|item1|[10, 11]|
+-----+--------+
```

Comment: thanks for the solution.. it worked like a charm.  As expected, not optimal, but functionally working for validation of the algorithm I am interested in